# What does $\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}} i_k^2$ equal?

Tags: number-theory, summation, binomial-coefficients, square-numbers, discrete-calculus

So, the figurate numbers $P_{k+1}(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}i_k = \binom{n+k}{k+1}$, which is quite neat.

I'm wondering what  the "square figurate numbers", $_{k+1}S(n)$, are equal to. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number) gives the answer for $_2S(n)$, which is just $\displaystyle \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$. I'm looking for the general case, however.

$$_{k+1}S(n) = \sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}} i_k^2$$

Given that *figurate number* is used in a few different ways, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number), under the section titled *Triangular numbers and their analogs in higher dimensions*, for the sense of the term that I'm using here.

Comment: Use the fact that $i_k^2=2\binom{i_k}{2}+i_k$.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Could you show me the proof for that? I had no idea. Though, in my derivations, I figured out the higher-dimensional analog of that identity. I guess I could prove your identity through that higher-dimensional analog?

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein No need. I just proved it myself. I can now self-answer this question.

Comment: Note that you can write $i_k=\sum_{i_{k+1}=1}^{i_k} 1$, so $\displaystyle \sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}i_k=\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}\sum_{i_{k+1}=1}^{i_k} 1=\sum_{1\le i_{k+1}\le\dots\le i_1\le n}1=\binom{k+1+n-1}{k+1}=\binom{n+k}{k+1}$. This is because $1\le i_{k+1}\le\dots\le i_1\le n$ if and only if $1\le i_{k+1}<i_k+1<i_{k-1}+2<\dots<i_1+k\le n+k$, so you are counting $(k+1)$-tuples in $\{1,\dots,n+k\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a simple observation:

$$ n^2 = \underbrace{n+n+\ \dots \ + n}_{n \  \text{times}}$$

This observation allows us to switch over to a sigma function.

$$n^2 = n+ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i) + i  = n + 2\binom n2$$

From here, evaluating $_{k+1}S(n)$ follows simply from the evaluation of $P_k(n)$.

$$\begin{align} _{k+1}S(n) &= \sum_{i_1=1}^n \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}} i_k^2 \\[2ex] &= \sum_{i_1=1}^n \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}  i_k + 2\binom{i_k}2 
 \\[2ex] &=  \binom{n+k}{k+1} +  2\binom{n+k+1}{k+2}\end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

More generally $$\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\dots\sum_{i_k=1}^{i_{k-1}}f(i_k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{n,k,i}f(i),\qquad c_{n,k,i}=\binom{n-i+k-1}{k-1}$$ (indeed, $c_{n,k,i}$ [counts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) sequences $(i_1,\dots,i_{k-1})$ such that $n\geqslant i_1\geqslant\dots\geqslant i_{k-1}\geqslant i$).

In terms of generating functions, if the above sum is $S(n,k,f)$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)z^n=g(z)\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty S(n,k,f)z^n=\frac{g(z)}{(1-z)^k}.$$

In our case $f(n)=n^2$ gives $g(z)=\dfrac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^3}$ and the answer $\dbinom{n+k}{k+2}+\dbinom{n+k+1}{k+2}$.